# Image compression and CPU usage

Tags: android, bitmap, image-compression

Android and a `Bitmap` class which has a `Compress` method ([see here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream))).

Compress has a `quality parameter`. According to the documentation, when compressing to JPEG:

> Compress to the JPEG format. quality of 0 means compress for the
> smallest size. 100 means compress for max visual quality.

My question is: will using a higher value (e.g. 100) use more CPU (i.e. take longer) than a lower value (e.g.50)?

I would expect the answer to be, "Yes, because doing more compression takes longer"... but I really do not know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Jpeg more quality means less compression, therefore less CPU usage.

More quality doesn't mean it will make the photo nicer, this is a misconception. In Jpeg, more quality means **do not compress so much and keep as near quality to the original photo as possible.** Compression reduces the current quality.

Towards 100 means less compression to keep quality, so it uses less CPU time as it needs to compress less.
Towards 0, means more compression in exchange of quality, so it uses more CPU time as it needs to compress more.

- More compression (direction to 0) = less quality, smaller file size, more CPU usage.
- Less compression (direction to 100) = more quality, bigger file size, less CPU usage.

What you need to consider, is that in Android Jpeg compression is implemented natively in C/C++, therefore is very fast. So the CPU time isn't a big factor to be taken much into account, considering that you should compress for best performance in a background thread.

Also you should avoid for most scenarios to use 100% quality, being optimal any value between 80% to 95%.

100% quality means no compression at all (so the best quality), but consequently can potentially produce huge files.